# My ISP is blocking my website?

Tags: dns, hosting, traceroute

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask this. If not, please tell me where.

I hosted my website in awardspace.com but now I am unable to connect to my site or awardspace.com. This happened a couple of times before, but now it happens very often. At first I thought it was just a crappy hosting service, but then I realized that awardspace and my site have been always online...it is just being blocked by a damn server. 
I can access my website and awardspace from any proxy. But from spain, I can't.

This is the traceroute:

```
traceroute to awardspace.com (82.197.131.36), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)  7.446 ms  6.969 ms  8.445 ms
 2  89.red-80-58-67.staticip.rima-tde.net (80.58.67.89)  56.382 ms  67.697 ms  58.488 ms
 3  41.red-80-58-76.staticip.rima-tde.net (80.58.76.41)  53.632 ms  57.980 ms  71.693 ms
 4  21.red-80-58-76.staticip.rima-tde.net (80.58.76.21)  65.289 ms  47.801 ms  48.096 ms
 5  so2-0-0-0-grtmadpe3.red.telefonica-wholesale.net (84.16.6.201)  76.706 ms *  51.404 ms
 6  xe8-1-0-0-grtpartv2.red.telefonica-wholesale.net (84.16.15.210)  66.847 ms  66.923 ms  65.311 ms
 7  213.140.55.50 (213.140.55.50)  77.796 ms  116.578 ms  80.169 ms
 8  xe-0-3-1.fra21.ip4.tinet.net (89.149.186.37)  136.179 ms
    xe-3-1-1.fra21.ip4.tinet.net (89.149.181.162)  98.915 ms
    xe-0-3-1.fra21.ip4.tinet.net (89.149.186.37)  104.872 ms
 9  eunetworks-gw.ip4.tinet.net (77.67.72.150)  80.423 ms  96.706 ms  129.389 ms
10  ae2-irt1.dus03.de.as13237.net (217.71.96.117)  84.497 ms  86.116 ms  79.715 ms
11  xe3-0-0.irt1.dus53.de.as13237.net (217.71.96.113)  82.364 ms  83.968 ms  81.745 ms
12  xe0-2-0.irt1.han87.de.as13237.net (217.71.96.77)  86.432 ms  89.351 ms  85.103 ms
13  xe0-2-0.irt1.ham21.de.as13237.net (217.71.96.89)  105.067 ms  90.882 ms *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
```

Is there a solution for this? Or should I just change hosting?

thanx in advance

Answer (score 3):

Actually you're probably not seeing a block, a block would be there permanently, you are probably seeing some routing problems between your ISP (or their provider) and the network you need to reach. If it were your ISP, you'd be seeing the traffic dropped much sooner. Notice the traffic gets to somewhere in Germany from the last tinet, it goes to Dusseldorf, then Hanover, then Hamburg, all in the AS13237 network. If your traffic is dying there, it's usually a routing problem, unless there literally is no other route to that network, which would be awfully odd for a hosting provider.

If it's a common issue, it might be worth changing hosters.